# get value of the mapped value within a mapped value

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, groovy, key-value

I created a array as follows

```
def foo =
  [ "bar2":
        [ "x" : "a",
           "y":"b"
         ],
    "bar1":
        [ "x" : "n",
           "y":"m"
         ]

]
```

I tried to assign a var as follows:
def var = foo.get("bar1").get("g")

I need to assign the value n of key x from bar1 to a variable. How do i do that?

Comment: you have already done it change ```g``` to ```x```. like this: ```foo.get("bar1").get("x");```

Comment: Thanks. I found out my case for the key was uppercase in the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dot notation:

```
def value = foo.bar2.x
```

or use array notation:

```
def value2 = foo["bar2"]["x"]
```

or just invoke method `get`:

```
def value3 = foo.get("bar2").get("x")
```